# How are new Political Actions unlocked?

Tags: hearts-of-iron-4

I'm trying to learn Hearts of Iron 4. I have been doing lots of reading and watching of YouTube videos already, but I am still a little confused :D

Basically, I am playing as Britain. I haven't done much yet, other than choosing some research and putting some Divisions into Armies.

I saw in a video how somebody took over the USA as Britain somehow, but then they clicked the "Political Actions" section in the Events & Decisions tab, and they got an option to absorb Canada into the British Empire.

My question:
**How can I change the Political Actions available to me?** For example: is there a way to absorb Ireland?

I noticed that in the Focus Tree I can see things like "Secure Iraq", but these depend on other nations' worldwide events before I can start to unlock them.

I guess I just need a little help in general with how the game works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to make new political actions available. Sometimes completing certain focus adds it directly, sometimes it's the country need to have specific ideology (in your example, GB should switch to a non-aligned and become British Empire). Some thing become available if you're at war against major power.

Overall, for the sake of making it easier to learn, I would advise you to focus your attention on national focus tree - it is a more visible and predictable way of steering your country through the game.

You're correct that some focuses depend on actions of other countries. Often you can make those more likely to happen if those countries like you - having the same ideology and high opinion helps. But most focuses don't have those risks and requirements

Comment: Thanks for the help here. I have persevered with the game last night and see that there is much more I haven't even scratched upon yet. Its nice to see it written here to tell me some exact ways these options become available. I ended up giving up because the Czechoslovakia border was attacked and I clicked "Lets Defend Czechoslovakia!" But I tried eventually to move all my armies to it but none of my troops ever made it to the front line. I'll probably try a restart today and see how I get on

Comment: Also, are you aware about this resource: https://hoi4.paradoxwikis.com/Hearts_of_Iron_4_Wiki ? It's a lot of information, but you can glance it from time to time and get an better explanation of some game mechanics